# How can I change the "page not found" message?

Tags: 8, status-messages

I want to change the *page not found* error message.

Recently, message shows like *The requested page could not be found.*  I want to show *The requested page "/nvzmx,nvm,zxnv," could not be found.*

I don't want to create a custom page. I only want to change the error message given in the *page not found* page.

Comment: If you want custom page for "page not found" then create an new basic page with content that you want. After that set that newly created node in admin/config/system/site-information settings in ERROR PAGES section "Default 404 (not found) page".

Comment: Thanks For quick reply I know that but I want change my page not found message.

Comment: And that's exactly what you can do with this approach. The 404 message isn't just a message, it is a page. And you can configure it to use any node, on which you can then have whatever message/content you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by overwriting the route `system.404` with a custom controller:

**mymodule/src/Controller/MyHttp4xxController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class MyHttp4xxController extends ControllerBase {

  public function on404() {
    return [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Custom 404 message'),
    ];
  }
```

**mymodule.routing.yml**

```
system.404:
  path: '/system/404'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyHttp4xxController:on404'
    _title: 'Page not found'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

**mymodule.install**

```
<?php

function mymodule_install() {
  module_set_weight('mymodule', 1);
}
```

You have to be sure, that your module runs after the system module, so that you can overwrite the route from the system module. This is why you need to set the module weight to 1. You need to reinstall the module, when you implement this.

Comment: You do not necessarily need to modify the module_install method to get the desired effect. A RouteSubscriber that modifies the existing route can do the same thing: https://gist.github.com/mikecrittenden/4a796bddfe42afdf727094b0473449b6