# Customizing the Access Denied Page

Tags: 8

I'm trying to modify the text that shows on the standard Access Denied page.  I created a module and tried to extend the core class but while module installs fine the page does not get modified.  My first question is can Access denied be customized?

Comment: This link <a href="https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86559/how-can-i-convert-the-code-that-used-drupal-get-http-header-to-check-if-drupal">link</a> will help you customize message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access Denied is an exception and if you want to have control over any aspect how this is handled the best place is an exception event subscriber, see [How can we catch the acces denied exception in drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211195/how-can-we-catch-the-acces-denied-exception-in-drupal-8) for the general aspects or [Returning alternate HTTP codes for unpublished content in Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231195/returning-alternate-http-codes-for-unpublished-content-in-drupal-8) for an example how to change a 403 to a 404 exception.

> I'm trying to modify the text that shows on the standard Access Denied
>   page?

This question is specific for the text, see this answer for a 404 message, [How to change page not found page error message in drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218039/how-to-change-page-not-found-page-error-message-in-drupal-8/218050#218050), replace it with 403 for an access denied message.

> My first question is can Access denied be customized?

The standard way is of course in the basic site settings *admin/config/system/site-information*.

Comment: The How to change page not found was what I was looking for thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the Access Denied Page at the theme level. Use the following file name suggestion `page--403.html.twig`, while
`page--4xx.html.twig` my be used for any 400-level status code.

Docs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/twig-template-naming-conventions